# Bat File wait for remote input

Tags: batch-file

is it possible to make a bat file that waits for a remote command that is cross-domain? that way I can set up a bat file on my computer at home that clicks accept (for chrome remote desktop) when I send the remote command.

Comment: Fred, instead of having to make a bat file to accept the remote connection, couldn't you [setup a permanent connection instead?](https://superuser.com/questions/583602/how-to-set-chrome-remote-desktop-connection-to-never-timeout)

Comment: Its not just for this. I have need it for other random things as well

Comment: Okay. Let's figure out what the problem is exactly then and provide you with a solution.

Just to clarify, you want to run a script when the RDP (remote desktop protocol) request comes in, that clicks "accept" and may also do another set of actions as well. Correct?

Comment: If the two networks can talk to each other without any firewall issues you should be able to use the [waitfor](https://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html) command.

Comment: If you are unable to do @Squashman's, then the other option would be a `for` loop running on client station with an `if exist C:\foo\bar.txt`, then from the command station create the `bar.txt` file via robocopy or an echo, etc onto the client station at the time you want to trigger

Comment: is it possible to do it by email or something so it works cross domain? my router does not work with port forwarding (thats another issue). is there a way to set up a middle man? it could create a file on the web, and my computer would check for that web adress?

Comment: @FredTheDoggy, this is no longer a programming issue.  The expectation for questions on StackOverFlow is that you have some code that you need help with.  You have no code and the scope of your problem is now beyond programming.